# Wish to confirm the price for IBM Bluemix Cloud Watson Tone Analyzer Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, analyzer, watson, price

We had some misunderstanding and disputes of Bluemix Cloud price for different services before. Here, we wish to confirm the price of Watson Tone Analyzer Service on this page:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/tone-analyzer.html#pricing-block

Based on our understanding of the above page, the first thousand API calls to the Tone Analyzer Service used in our each app per month are FREE. Can we see some records of this API calls to Tone Analyzer Service inside our account on Bluemix cloud?

Wish Bluemix staff to confirm this soon. Thanks

Comment: Open a support ticket on bluemix.

Comment: Your Bluemix encourages us to post Q here. Thus, all people can learn about this.

Comment: That's for technical questions.  For billing and service issues you can contact support directly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the webpage.

First thousand API calls per month are **FREE**

- Additional 1 - 250,000 calls are **$0.0088 per call**
- 250,001 - 5,000,000 calls are **$0.0013 per call**
- 5,000,000+ calls are **$0.0008 per call**

It doesn't matter if you have one or multiple apps. The only thing that matters is how many times you call the Tone Analyzer service.

For example, three applications doing 600 calls will be the same as one doing 1800 calls. In this case, you will pay:

```
1800(total calls) - 1000(free) = 800 
800(remaining) * 0.0088 = $7.04
```

Comment: Great ! Your explanation should be added to the above price page so as to avoid the confusing. So, First thousand API calls per month are FREE is per user account and not Per App.

Comment: We are still waiting for the reply on this Q before we use Watson Tone Analyzer Service  : Can we see some records of this API calls to Tone Analyzer Service inside our account on Bluemix cloud?

Comment: For those that read this at a later time, the Bluemix site should be the main point of contact. As prices are subject to change, and IBM will not be required to maintain this answer.

Comment: I guess that Bluemix will email the price change to its users ahead of the time, right?

Comment: Yes @eGlobeBiz, it will email the price changes.

Comment: Can we see some records of this API calls to Tone Analyzer Service inside our account on Bluemix cloud?  So, we can decide to use this service or not based on the usage data.

Comment: There should be a Usage tab in your manage account page. If it isn't there then you can't.